# how to restart a personal wireless netgear router with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, wireless

How do configure an netgear wireless router in vb.net code? I want to restart my router and thought about disconnecting clients. This might be used to help a relative with their wireless router.

Edit:
OS Information:
Windows 7 SP1
.NET Framework 4.5 or above

Comment: The reason you are not getting replies and are getting downvotes is that this question is overly broad.

Comment: I just want to restart my netgear wireless router in vb.net. What's broad about that? Tell me?

Comment: actually this is a perfect question stated properly, the reason these idiots close the thread is because you're a VB developer and because they don't know the answer, two things which offend them and their fragile little ego's cannot handle the one-two punch. that's the reality of it. If I were you I would ask again, until I get my answer. These people must be filling in for CasperOne, SO trolls is what we call them, give em a little bit of power, and they abuse the hell out of it. They were probably bullied badly in high school and now they are bulling others to placate their emotional needs.

Comment: @Jeffery sorry forgot to quote you in the previous comment, anyway, the comment above this one I wrote for you... and the thread closing trolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First-off: you should never have to reboot your router under any circumstances (short of a firmware upgrade). If your modem/router "breaks" occasionally and requires a reboot to resume normal operation then something is wrong with it and you should seek a warranty replacement. A line de-sync should not require a reboot either.

With that disclaimer out of the way: there are two ways you can achieve your goal:

The first is to use the Telnet administration features present in your Netgear router (assuming they're enabled and operational). Writing a Telnet-client in code is trivial and an exercise left to the reader. It's just a matter of knowing the right commands to send to get it to reboot.

The second is to write a web client (using `HttpWebRequest`) that sends the series of HTTP requests to the router in the same way a human-directed-browser would if they were doing the reboot themselves. Use a tool like Firefox's "Live HTTP Headers" to see what HTTP requests need to be sent. Be wary of problems with cookie retention in HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Thank you. I understand I understand. I understand so people are rude on this website(not you). Note: I think it was related to a firmware upgrade before but now its more of a line or bandwidth Throttling issue because it seems like it drops the internet after I have downloaded a certain amount and then crashs (I do not know why in my area I get the 1.5mbps connection).

Comment: I can post my router model if you want to look it up for some links. If i knew how to setup telnet on the router correctly I would not be sitting here I would do it myself.

Comment: @Dal Actually, I want to reboot my router and the routers of people who use my software... to give myself and them the ability to change our IP address. Unless you know of a better way to send a command, say, through UPnP or any other mechanism that doesn't require a login with user/pass, then that would be great. Calling the "Disconnect" (or was it "Reconnect?") UPnP command doesn't change the IP address on almost all routers, even though it is supposed to and does on one particular brand/model of router that I owned and tested on. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jeffery if you get it to work, do tell us about what you did and how you did it. Of course, if you have code, paste your code examples. Of course, upon sharing your methods, I'd also be more than happy to share the method I discovered (as referenced/mentioned in passing above) with you.

Comment: Post a link in the main comments where I am asking my question above or as an alterative answer.